# update external list data using infopath codebehind

Tags: development, infopath, external-content-type, external-list

I know that I can update my ECT record (using InfoPath forms I created for the external lists), by passing the BdcIdentity (ID) to the form and it will find that record and enable me to edit.

How do I edit a record without the BdcIdentity ID. Say I know some of the other IDs I need to uniquely identify a record. EG, MyID=1

How can I get the infopath form to retreive the record where column MyID=1?? so I can update.

thanks,
KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out in the end after playing with the ECT Operations.
You have to ensure that the Read Item, Read List and Update operations all take the same parameters and that the Read Item and Read List return the same columns.

After setting the above up you can use the BdcIdentity (which is a composition of all the input parameters) to update the External List data.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perplexed,

For this I usually write a WCF Web Service which accepts ID and returns data accordingly, populate them on form for user to edit and on submit call the web service again to update to datasource!

You can directly update to the data source you are using like SQL Server or using SharePoint Object Model for BDCIdentity!

If there exist any better solution than this, I would also like to know :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems a bit long winded but I guess if that is the only way.... so you create a webservice project from scratch and code methods to get data from and update the database?

Comment: Exactly, at least that is the only way I know! Lets wait until some other professionals view your question, maybe we find a better solution to this :)